# Format a Word 2007 table to display currency values

Tags: microsoft-word-2007, currency-format

When I apply a formula to the table, it allows me to select a format. How do I apply a currency format on the numbers to the other cells in Word 2007?

Comment: You could consider embedding an *Excel worksheet* instead of using a *table*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out if you insert a formula and just use `= 15000` instead of `=sum(ABOVE)`, it gives the results I was looking for.

I know I could have inserted an Excel spreadsheet, but I had so many tables that were already styled and didn't want to redo the work.

For clarity, to be able to insert a formula into a Word document you must be inside a table. Using the `Table Tools - Layout` ribbon section there is the `Formula` button near the `AZ Sort` button.

Comment: This worked great, only downside to this, it does not seem like Word can auto sum a column that you do this to properly. At the very least it can't autosum if you use a number format where negative is displayed as ($100.00). I did the autosum then applied this to the cells afterwards, so it worked alright.

Answer (score 1):

If you're dealing with numbers and currency, it may be worth using an Excel worksheet embedded in to the Word document.

**Insert > Object > "Microsoft Office Excel Worksheet"**

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly sure if it works on formulas, but have you tried Word's [Format Painter](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/word/HP011684261033.aspx)?

Comment: Crappy. :(  You may be stuck copying and pasting cells to get your formatting, and then adjusting the pasted versions.